# Put commit position in a branch in build number format

Tags: git, svn, teamcity

I'm trying to set a sequential value in my project build number format. The intention is to set a sequential number that should be the same for a commit building in different agents and be incremented for each new commit on the same branch.

Using the build number is impossible because sometimes we have to cancel some builds and the different agents running the build diverge. Using the commit hash sets the same build number, but is not sequential.

I thought about the commit position on a branch, but not finding a way to make a script go through a branch and count.

Using this scrip for now on each build configuration

```
$BuildNumber = "%Major.Minor%"
$Hash = "%build.vcs.number%"
$ShortHash = $Hash.substring(0,3)
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$BuildNumber.$ShortHash']"
```

Any knoweledge on this?

Comment: You could consider to use the command "git rev-list --count <commit>" to get a sequential number for a given commit. More info execute "git help rev-list".

Comment: Trimmed output of `git describe` (with some tag in parents) will work also

Answer (score 2):

I would have a look at GitVersion, a tool to help you achieve Semantic Versioning on your project. This will go through the branch and calculate the commit position for you, generating a build number to that effect.

The tool offers a Meta Runner for TeamCity, but checkouts must happen on the agent (which it sounds like you're doing) as they need to recreate the git repository.

[How it works](https://gitversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/more-info/how-it-works/)

[TeamCity setup](https://gitversion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/teamcity/)

Hope this helps